# Python: cleaner list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is there a cleaner way to write this:

```
for w in [w for w in words if w != '']:
```

I want to loop over a dictionary `words`, but only words that `!= ''`. Thanks!

Comment: "words that aren't whitespace", as a commentor below points out, *isn't the same as `!= ""`*. Use the `isspace` method if that's what you need.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke, I don't mean whitespace (edited).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a listcomp here.  Just write:

```
for w in words:
    if w != '':
        # ...
```

Comment: @Daniel Goldberg, who said that, i thought 'for' was for iterating, and as OP is doing it it is overkill, @dan04 +1, that is the correct way...IMO

Comment: If you don't want to have another indentation level, you could always have `if w == "": continue` or `if not w: continue`, which is something I see pretty often.

Comment: @Goldberg: Listcomps are preferred over loops that do .append to a list, not over loops in general.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are after the keys, why not try:

```
[w for w in words if w]
```

Answer (score 1):

`filter(lambda w: w != '', words)` or `filter(None, words)`

this is suggestion, it may not be the best solution for your problem.

Comment: "filter(P, S) is almost always written clearer as [x for x in S if P(x)]" - Guido van Rossum.

Comment: @Nou I am partial towards functional stuff.  at the same time guido really dislike them.  they have their place, but probably not for OP problem

Comment: Your first snippet is a SyntaxError (I think you mean `!=`—`not` is something different). Using `filter` isn't somehow *more functional* than using a list comprehension (an idea we stole from no other but Haskell!), and using `filter` and `map` with lambdas seems downright silly to me.

Comment: What do you mean by "functional stuff"? Do you mean the name `filter`? How is it semantically different from a list comprehension (which itself was borrowed from a pure functional language)?

Comment: @Nou python manual calls them functional tools, hence functional stuff.  sometimes I use them because they make code little bit cleaner in certain cases. semantically, that probably not different.

Comment: Why is this getting voted down? It may not suite some people's taste, but it's entirely valid.

Answer (score 1):

Testing that an element does not equal `''` isn't going to filter out whitespace elements. If that's what you're after, you probably want to use `str.isspace` (or a regular expression).

If you use a list comprehension, you'll make an extra copy of the list as an intermediary object. Probably not a big deal, but a generator won't use the extra memory.

I'd do it like this, with a generator:

```
for word in (w for w in words if not w.isspace()):
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is sub optimal. You're iterating over the list `words` twice - once in the list comprehension to create the non-null terms and again in the loop to do the processing. It would be better if you used a genexp like so.

```
for w in (x for x in words if x): process(w)
```

That way, the genexp will lazily return a list of non-nulls.

Comment: `for w in words: if x: process(w)` seems simpler, shorter, and clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

What does the body of the outer for loop do?

If it's a function call you could potentially just do:

`[f(w) for w in words if w != '']`